# remove a structure node cause another problem

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, structure

I am trying to add the words of two files (there could be more) in the structure. This works. However I have an option to remove some words (which are in **stop.txt**) from the structure. This causes incorrect output when it is activated and two files are in.

For example in **test.txt** I have some random strings:

```
kiio
luio
kiio
ohaio
lol
```

In **test1.txt**:

```
vola
kiio
kiio
haio
lol
```

and **stop.txt**:

```
luio
kiio
```

Output when `remove_word` is activated:

```
lol     test.txt        [1] {5}                                                                                                
lol     %~      [1] {5}                                                                                                        
lol     %~      [1] {5}                                                                                                        
luio    test.txt        [1] {2}                                                                                                
ohaio   test.txt        [1] {4}                                                                                                
vola    test1.txt       [1] {1}
```

When it's not:

```
kiio    test.txt        [2] {1,3}     I need to have two nodes with the same word but different `fileno`                                                                                         
kiio    test1.txt       [2] {2,3}                                                                                              
lol     test.txt        [1] {5}                                                                                                
lol     test1.txt       [1] {5}                                                                                                
luio    test.txt        [1] {2}                                                                                                
ohaio   test.txt        [1] {4}                                                                                                
vola    test1.txt       [1] {1}                                                                                                
haio    test1.txt       [1] {4}
```

The problem I think is in the function `remove_word` but I am not sure because it works (removes the words) for only one file.

Here are the structure definitions:

```
typedef struct _word {
    char *s;                /* the word */
    int count;              /* number of times word occurs */
    int *line_numbers;      // Array of line numbers
    int num_line_numbers;   // Size of the array of line numbers
    char *fileno;
} word;
// Creating a struct to hold the data. I find it's easier
typedef struct {
    word *words;      // The array of word structs
    int num_words;    // The size of the array
} word_list;
```

`remove_word` function:

```
void remove_word(word_list *words, const char *word_to_delete) {
    for (int i = 0; i < words->num_words; i++) {
        if (0 == strcmp(words->words[i].s, word_to_delete)) {
            // TODO: handle special case where there is only 1 word in list

            // Calc number of words after found word
            int number_of_words_to_right = words->num_words - i - 1;
            // Free mem
            free(words->words[i].s);
            free(words->words[i].line_numbers);
            free(words->words[i].fileno);

            // Copy remaining words
            memcpy(&words->words[i], &words->words[i + 1], sizeof(word) * number_of_words_to_right);
            // Resize the array (technically not required)
            word *tmp = realloc(words->words, sizeof(word) * --words->num_words);
            if (NULL == tmp) exit(0);
            words->words = tmp;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Main:

```
int main() {
    int i, n, m;
    int option = 0;
    n = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r"); 

    word_list *words = malloc(sizeof(word_list));
    if (NULL == words)
        exit(0);
    memset(words, 0, sizeof(word_list));

    char s[1000];
    int line_number = 1;
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), file)) {
        char *word = strtok(s, " ");
        while (word != NULL) {
            size_t len = strlen(word);
            if (len > 0 && word[len - 1] == '\n')
                word[--len] = 0;
            insert_word(words, word, line_number, "test.txt");
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        line_number += 1;
    }
    fclose(file);

    FILE *file1 = fopen("test1.txt", "r"); 

    line_number = 1;
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), file)) {
        char *word = strtok(s, " ");
        while (word != NULL) {
            size_t len = strlen(word);
            if (len > 0 && word[len - 1] == '\n')
                word[--len] = 0;
            insert_word(words, word, line_number, "test1.txt");
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        line_number += 1;
    }
    fclose(file1);

     if (option == 0) {
         FILE *stopfile = fopen("stop.txt", "r"); /* should check the result */
         char fline[256];

         while (fgets(fline, sizeof(fline), stopfile)) {
             remove_word(words, fline);
         }
         fclose(stopfile);
    }

    printlist(words);

    for (int i = 0; i < words->num_words; i++) {
        free(words->words[i].s);
        free(words->words[i].line_numbers);
        free(words->words[i].fileno);
    }
    free(words->words);
    free(words);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot test your program because you did not provide the source code for `insert_word` and `printlist`.

Yet there are multiple problems in the posted code:

- in the `remove_word` function, when the word is found and removed, you should decrement `i` so the loop tests the same index in the next iteration, in case the same word is present in both files.
- in the second reading loop, you read from `file` but this `FILE*` was closed and you used a different `FILE` pointer `file1` to open the second file **test1.txt**. This has undefined behavior. You might be lucky and `file1` may point to the same location in memory as `file` by chance. Just use the same variable `file` for all files, or better: use a separate function to read word from a file given as an argument.
- you do not strip the trailing newline from the words you pass to `remove_word`, so nothing will be removed from the dictionary.

Here is a modified version of your program:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _word {
    char *s;                /* the word */
    int count;              /* number of times word occurs */
    int *line_numbers;      // Array of line numbers
    int num_line_numbers;   // Size of the array of line numbers
    char *fileno;
} word;

// Creating a struct to hold the data. I find it's easier
typedef struct {
    word *words;      // The array of word structs
    int num_words;    // The size of the array
} word_list;

char *strlower(char *s) {
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        s[i] = (char)tolower((unsigned char)s[i]);
    }
    return s;
}

void printlist(const word_list *words) {
    for (int i = 0, j; i < words->num_words;) {
        const word *wp = &words->words[i];
        /* check for identical words from different files */
        for (j = i + 1; j < words->num_words; j++) {
            if (strcmp(wp->s, words->words[j].s) != 0)
                break;
        }
        printf("%s\t[%d]", wp->s, j - i);
        const char *prefix = "";
        for (; i < j; i++, wp++) {
            printf("%s\t%s\t[%d]\t{%d", prefix, wp->fileno, wp->count, wp->line_numbers[0]);
            prefix = "\t";
            for (int k = 1; k < wp->num_line_numbers; k++) {
                printf(",%d", wp->line_numbers[k]);
            }
            printf("}\n");
        }
    }
}

/* insert the word in the dictionary.
 * words are inserted in lexicographical order,
 * identical words are inserted in order of calls to insert_word
 */
int insert_word(word_list *words, const char *s, int line_number, const char *filename) {
    int i, j;
    word *wp;
    /* locate the word in the dictionary */
    for (i = 0, j = words->num_words; i < j;) {
        int m = i + (j - i) / 2;
        if (strcmp(words->words[m].s, s) < 0)
            i = m + 1;
        else
            j = m;
    }
    wp = &words->words[i];
    /* check identical words already in the dictionary */
    for (; i < words->num_words && !strcmp(wp->s, s); i++, wp++) {
        if (!strcmp(wp->fileno, filename)) {
            /* found word from the same file */
            wp->count++;
            /* check if word appears for a new line number */
            for (j = 0; j < wp->num_line_numbers; j++) {
                if (wp->line_numbers[j] == line_number)
                    break;
            }
            if (j == wp->num_line_numbers) {
                /* add a new line */
                int *lp = realloc(wp->line_numbers, (j + 1) * sizeof(*wp->line_numbers));
                if (lp == NULL)
                    return 1;
                wp->line_numbers = lp;
                wp->line_numbers[wp->num_line_numbers++] = line_number;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    /* insert new word into the dictionary at offset i */
    /* allocate all elements for easier memory management */
    char *new_s = strdup(s);
    char *new_filename = strdup(filename);
    int *new_line_numbers = malloc(1 * sizeof(*wp->line_numbers));
    if (!new_s || !new_filename || !new_line_numbers) {
        free(new_s);
        free(new_filename);
        free(new_line_numbers);
        return 1;
    }
    word *new_words = realloc(words->words, (words->num_words + 1) * sizeof(*words->words));
    if (new_words == NULL) {
        free(new_s);
        free(new_filename);
        free(new_line_numbers);
        return 1;
    }
    words->words = new_words;
    /* shift the rest of the dictionary to the right */
    wp = &words->words[i];
    memmove(wp + 1, wp, (words->num_words - i) * sizeof(*wp));
    wp->s = new_s;
    wp->count = 1;
    wp->line_numbers = new_line_numbers;
    wp->line_numbers[0] = line_number;
    wp->num_line_numbers = 1;
    wp->fileno = new_filename;
    words->num_words++;
    return 0;
}

int remove_word(word_list *words, const char *word_to_delete) {
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < words->num_words; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(words->words[i].s, word_to_delete)) {
            // Calc number of words after found word
            int number_of_words_to_right = words->num_words - i - 1;
            // Free mem
            free(words->words[i].s);
            free(words->words[i].line_numbers);
            free(words->words[i].fileno);

            if (--words->num_words == 0) {
                free(words->words);
                words->words = NULL;
            } else {
                // Copy remaining words if any
                memcpy(&words->words[i], &words->words[i + 1],
                       sizeof(word) * number_of_words_to_right);
                // Resize the array (technically not required)
                word *tmp = realloc(words->words, sizeof(word) * words->num_words);
                if (tmp != NULL)
                    words->words = tmp;
            }
            found++;
            i--; // restart from the same index in the loop
        }
    }
    return found;
}

/* read all words from filename into word_list
 * return 0 if no error.
 */
int read_file(word_list *words, const char *filename) {
    char s[1000];
    int line_number = 1;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), file)) {
        char *word = strtok(s, " \n");
        while (word != NULL) {
            if (insert_word(words, strlower(word), line_number, filename)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error inserting from %s at line %d\n", filename, line_number);
                fclose(file);
                return 1;
            }
            word = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
        line_number += 1;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int option = 1;
    word_list *words = calloc(sizeof(word_list), 1);
    if (words == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    read_file(words, "test.txt");
    read_file(words, "test1.txt");

    if (option != 0) {
        char s[1000];
        FILE *file = fopen("stop.txt", "r"); /* should check the result */
        if (file == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", "stop.txt");
        } else {
            while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), file)) {
                char *word = strtok(s, " \n");
                while (word != NULL) {
                    remove_word(words, strlower(word));
                    word = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                }
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
    printlist(words);

    for (int i = 0; i < words->num_words; i++) {
        free(words->words[i].s);
        free(words->words[i].line_numbers);
        free(words->words[i].fileno);
    }
    free(words->words);
    free(words);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
haio    [1]     test1.txt       [1]     {4}
lol     [2]     test.txt        [1]     {5}
                test1.txt       [1]     {5}
ohaio   [1]     test.txt        [1]     {4}
vola    [1]     test1.txt       [1]     {1}
```

Comment: it seems to be a problem of www.onlinegdb.com. I used to work there until now

Comment: I compiled the code on it and i got `ohaio   test.txt        [1]     {5}                                                                                            
lol     test.txt        [1]     {5}                                                                                            
vola    test1.txt       [1]     {1}                                                                                            
lol      ��     [1]     {27780336}                                                                                             
lol      ��     [1]     {27780336}`

Comment: is there any way to print sequentially the same strings?

Comment: Which code did you compile? yours or mine? There might be problems in your implementation of `insert_word` and `printlist`. To print identical words sequentially, the best is to insert them this way into the dictionary. I shall amend my answer for this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yours, but it's working. That compiler website seems not work correctly if you have pointers and malloc. Another thing, I am trying for the same strings which are in different files,   the first one same string that is printed to have next to it, the number of files it appeared for example if it is on both files would have a [2] next to it.

Comment: So the output in `[]` is not the `count` member, which I assumed was the number of times the word occurs in the file, which may be less than the number of lines it occurs in.

Comment: @Dbstack: In your expected output, `lol` appears once in 2 different files and the output shows `lol [1] {5}` for both files.

Comment: Sorry did i confused you? For each string of a file i keep a record at which lines it appeared. If a string appeared in two files I want to print it like string1 [2] file1.txt [count of lines for file1] {lines in file1} \n string1 file2.txt [count of lines for file2] {lines in file2}

Comment: im thinking to add a member in its struct and increment it

Comment: @Dbstack: I think it would be easier to compute this number on the fly in `printlist`. Note however that the output format is no longer consistent.

Comment: i was thinking for every string that is only at one file it could be string 3 [1]  fileno1.txt [counter] [lines it appeared]. For all the same strings in many files it could be the same for example if it is 3 it will be [3] for every same word

Comment: i dont know if its easy but i would print the same word one time like string1 [2] file1.txt [count of lines for file1] {lines in file1} \n file2.txt [count of lines for file2] {lines in file2}

Comment: @Dbstack: If you start the following lines with white space, if would make it easy to check visually.

Comment: how we could compute that number in printlist? it seems a good idea

Comment: @Dbstack: it is not difficult: look and learn from by updated answer.

Comment: just one more question, if the string has capital letters does it make it all lower case?

Comment: @Dbstack: just convert the characters to lowercase in the `insert_word()` and `remove_word()` functions: `for (size_t i = 0; s[i]; i++) { s[i] = tolower((unsigned char)s[i]); }`

Comment: chqrli thank you. Ok i might need to make the lowercase as function. So can i call it as function inside insert_word() and remove or it's better to do that in main?

Comment: @Dbstack: make it a function and apply it before searching for the word in the dictionary, for example `insert_word(words, strlower(word), line_number, filename)` and `remove_word(words, strlower(word))`. See the updated code.

Comment: it shows me a problem in this line for (size_t i = 0; s[i],i++) something with c99 i use devc++

Comment: @Dbstack: sorry, just a typo: the `,` should be a `;`.

Comment: Hello chqrlie,Sorry to disturb you again. I added some functions and a menu in the code based on print function but I have some problems. The first one it prints the string (from all files) that are equal with a string that user gives as inputor else gives a message.  it seems it doesn't print the menu again but just print the string and doesn't do anything. but I am not sure if that return it's creating any problem.The other function gets a character from user and finds and prints all the strings (from all files) that begin with this character. This function seems not to work correctly.

Comment: @Dbstack: I'm sorry, but I already spent too much time on this question. I cannot finish your code for you.

Comment: Can you explain me a bit the print function of your code? It doesn't returns any value or just return; and what this does for (int i = 0, j; i < words->num_words; ) {

Comment: this problem I have it's because the loop for (int i = 0, j; i < words->num_words; ) it doesn't i++

Comment: @Dbstack: `i` is incremented in the inner loop. In order to print the total number of occurrences, I added 2 loops inside the `for (int i = 0, j; i < words->num_words; )`: one that computes the total number of occurrences, that incrementing `j`, and a second one that increments `i` and prints the occurrences of the same word for each file. At the end of this second inner loop, `i` has been incremented by the number of entries that have the same word for different files.

Comment: ok thanks but why if i add an if to compare a word that is passed as function parameter with words->words[i].s right after the first for, the program never gets out from that for?

Comment: @Dbstack: I redesigned `printlist` to produce the desired output. If you want different semantics, you must adjust the code accordingly, but you must study it first and understand what it does. You must improve your skill level progressively and avoid patching functions you do not understand. C is not a friendly programming language to this regard: it is very easy to break a program and quite difficult to analyse unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Dbstack: sorry about that, there was a typo in `for (j = 0; j < wp->num_line_numbers; j++)`, the `j < ` was missing, causing an infinite loop with undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok thanks. Btw When I am running this on my computer it works fine. But when I run the code on linux centos with terminal and gcc -std=c99 it doesn't work correctly. I mean when I have the option to remove the words, when I print the list again it still shows them in. However this doesn't happen to my computer

Answer (score 0):

I found something, not sure if this is enough to fix the code: you have to decrease `num_words` when you remove a world from the array, try adding:

```
words->num_words--;
```

Below `words->words = tmp;` at the end of the if in the function `remove_word`

Comment: you mean `words->num_words--;` it fixes the line issue of some words but keeps some of the unwanted words

Comment: or maybe there are also some words missing. this is the output `luio    test.txt        [1] {2}                                                                                                
ohaio   test.txt        [1] {4}                                                                                                
lol     test.txt        [1] {5}                                                                                                
vola    test1.txt       [1] {1}  `